# delay before function which is bind with animationend

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to set delay before function execute which is bind with Img1 animation complete.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#Img1").bind.('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() {        
    $("#Img2").addClass("fadeOutRight animated");enter code here    
});
```

});

Comment: i am not sure how you want to use that but i think you can use delay in jquery .. see this link http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: remove the `.` after bind, should be `bind();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to delay the addClass right?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#Img1").bind.('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() {

    var delay = 500; // delay in milliseconds

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#Img2").addClass("fadeOutRight animated");
    }, delay);
});
```

Comment: setTimeout function is not executed!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
$("#img1").animate({
    //Do stuff.
},500).queue(function(){
     $("#Img2").addClass("fadeOutRight animated");
     $(this).dequeueu();
})
```